# Different stickers and boxes for “Mario & Luigi: Superstar Saga”; what’s the difference?

Tags: version-differences, mario-superstar-saga

I’m looking to buy a copy of *Mario & Luigi: Superstar Saga*, and noticed that a few copies of the cartridge have different stickers and some have different box art, but I can’t find any information on why or what the difference(s) may be.

I thought maybe it’s a regional thing, but I can find some photos on Google Images that show different region codes on the same images (last two).

Can anyone tell me why there’s at least three different sticker designs and three different box arts?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_&_Luigi:_Superstar_Saga), the first image in your question is the North American box art. Upon going to the website in tiny print in the bottom-right corner of your second image, [it appears to be custom, fan-made box art for the game](http://www.vgboxart.com/view/19101/mario.&.luigi.superstar.saga/) (that got criticism for being "way too crowded"). Number three [also seems to be fan-made](http://www.vgboxart.com/forums/showthread.php?10181-Mario-amp-Luigi-Superstar-Saga-GBA).

As for the cartridges, I'm not sure. Number three and two seem to be the North American versions (with number two not for resale), and numbers one and four seem to be European cartridges. I don't know why number one has different "cartridge art" though. The fourth looks suspicious to me because of the way the *Nintendo Seal of Quality* is printed, but perhaps that's the way European cartridges are stamped. The first cartridge lacks the Nintendo logo and is different from the other three, leading me to believe it's fake.

**TL;DR**, the first box art is the real one, and I believe number three is the "real" cartridge.

Comment: *> …fan art…* Blast Google Images! `:-)` *> …Nintendo Seal/Logo…* Good point. I can’t help but wonder if some are labels that people printed out to replace one that was damaged—I intend to do the same thing with my copy of *Wario Land 3* on which half of the label is gone. Unfortunately there are no repositories of high-quality sticker scans so, it requires some Photoshopping to get a decent one. Either way, I’ll have to double-check if the price is *really* good, otherwise it’s not worth the risk (even though the guy with the blue cartridge said he tested it and it’s the right game and works.

Comment: The code on the blue-background cartridge is *AGB-AMLP-EUR*.

Comment: Hmm, that guy on eBay has another game with [different cart-art](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wrxSX.jpg) from the [normal one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pIodQ.jpg). (Google Images found only *one* [other copy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RkP44.jpg) with that art, but none of the other game, M&L.) What’s more is that his games have no bids and are expiring in less than two hours, while other copies have plenty of bids. I think I’ll steer clear, just in case.

Also, the [European version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ABjy4.jpg) of that game also has the *CE* stamp and a circular seal instead of an oval one.

Comment: Cartridge label 1 is fake - it has a European serial (which doesn't actually exist - it would have been [M&M's Blast!](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/567503-mms-blast/data), but that was never released in Europe), but it also has an ESRB rating (Europe uses PEGI), and no Seal of Quality. Label 4 is legit - it matches my own European copy.